# Obtener primer registro sin usar subconsultas

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, oracle

Estoy tratando de obtener el primer registro que salga en la siguiente consulta `SQL`:

```
SELECT G305.G305S01 AS SALDO
    FROM BI_SRC.GSCF300 G300, BI_SRC.GSCF305 G305 
    WHERE G300.G300CTA = 1024004598
    AND G300.G300UUID = G305.G301UUID
    GROUP BY  G305.G305FDIA, G305.G305S01
    ORDER BY G305.G305FDIA DESC
```

Problema con el **ROWNUM**

Si a la consulta ya antes dada, le agrego la funcion **ROWNUM** me trae es un resultado aleatorio.

```
SELECT G305.G305S01 AS SALDO
    FROM BI_SRC.GSCF300 G300, BI_SRC.GSCF305 G305 
    WHERE G300.G300CTA = 1024004598
    AND G300.G300UUID = G305.G301UUID
    AND ROWNUM <= 1
    GROUP BY  G305.G305FDIA, G305.G305S01
    ORDER BY G305.G305FDIA DESC
```

Al utilizar el **ROWNUM** como una subconsulta, es decir:

```
SELECT * FROM ( 

    SELECT G305.G305S01 AS SALDO
    FROM BI_SRC.GSCF300 G300, BI_SRC.GSCF305 G305 
    WHERE G300.G300CTA = 1024004598
    AND G300.G300UUID = G305.G301UUID
    GROUP BY  G305.G305FDIA, G305.G305S01
    ORDER BY G305.G305FDIA DESC

    )
WHERE ROWNUM <= 1
```

Al realizarlo con una subconsulta me trae el resultado esperado, pero tarda mucho en ejecutar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El problema es la pseudocolumna `rownum`.

La [documentacion](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns009.htm) de esa columna describe el problema.

El problema se basa en saber en que momento se asigna ese rownum a la fila devuelta.

Veamos el problema en tus ejemplos:

```
SELECT G305.G305S01 AS SALDO
FROM BI_SRC.GSCF300 G300, BI_SRC.GSCF305 G305 
WHERE G300.G300CTA = 1024004598
AND G300.G300UUID = G305.G301UUID
AND ROWNUM <= 1
GROUP BY  G305.G305FDIA, G305.G305S01
ORDER BY G305.G305FDIA DESC
```

Aca, rownum se aplica en cualquier momento. Si no entraste por indice, trae la primer fila que se le ocurra, esa fila cumple con el rownum, y se la queda. Cuando quiere traer la segunda, le asigna rownum = 2, por lo tanto no cumple con el where y la descarta, y asi con todo el resto. Queda solamente la primer fila que encontro.

Si entraste por indice, o casualidad siempre va a traer la misma fila, pero solamente porque aprovecha el indice para buscar una fila mas rapido.

En tu segundo caso

```
SELECT * FROM ( 

    SELECT G305.G305S01 AS SALDO
    FROM BI_SRC.GSCF300 G300, BI_SRC.GSCF305 G305 
    WHERE G300.G300CTA = 1024004598
    AND G300.G300UUID = G305.G301UUID
    GROUP BY  G305.G305FDIA, G305.G305S01
    ORDER BY G305.G305FDIA DESC

    )
WHERE ROWNUM <= 1
```

Si funciona, y porque? porque aca aplica rownum a todo el conjunto de filas generado. O sea, hace el query, agrupa, ordena y despues enumera las filas y trae la primera, que siempre va a ser la misma por el orden.

Si esa consulta tarda, deberias ver temas de indices y otras cosas, pero esa es la forma correcta de hacerlo.

Comment: Excelente! Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Creo que la solución sería utlizar `FETCH`

```
SELECT G305.G305S01 AS SALDO
FROM BI_SRC.GSCF300 G300, BI_SRC.GSCF305 G305 
WHERE G300.G300CTA = 1024004598
AND G300.G300UUID = G305.G301UUID
GROUP BY  G305.G305FDIA, G305.G305S01
ORDER BY G305.G305FDIA DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

Comment: fetch es otra opcion si esta en el oracle que lo admita, pero igual hay que chequear el explain plan, porque si no tiene indices va a terminar con el mismo problema que tiene. Fetch va a ejecutar todo, y despues va a devolver lo que necesita.

Comment: @gbianchi ciertamente, el problema de los índices sigue siendo el que representa el cuello de botella de la subconsulta

Comment: ¿no debería, por fuerza, calcularse todo el resultado para poder saber cual es el primer elemento? Lo pregunto por que igual si se usara la función analítica  ROW_NUMBER()  el proceso tendría que calcular el orden primero para saber cual es el primer elemento.

Comment: @AlvaroC. Claro, de hecho es como dice @gbianchi, se ejecuta la consulta y `FETCH` trae el primer elemento, no hace falta `ROWNUM` y tampoco hace falta realizar una subconsulta, obviamente si tu oracle admite `FETCH`, deberías verificarlo

Answer (score 0):

Usalo de esta forma:

```
SELECT top 1 G305.G305S01 AS SALDO
FROM BI_SRC.GSCF300 G300, BI_SRC.GSCF305 G305 
WHERE G300.G300CTA = 1024004598
AND G300.G300UUID = G305.G301UUID`
GROUP BY  G305.G305FDIA, G305.G305S01
ORDER BY G305.G305FDIA DESC;
```

Comment: Podriás explicar por qué tu query es una mejor opción? De esta manera será de utildiad a otros desarrolladores. Gracias.